# SIFT keypoint detector

Tags: matlab, graphics, image-processing, sift

It seems that nothing changes on a jpg file after running the SIFT demo program here http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/keypoints/. Does anyone know how it works?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

SIFT is an algorithm that generate keypoints based on its renowned automatic feature detection capabilities.  Those keypoints would most likely be taken to compare with or match against other images.   The image itself is not being modified.  Rather, we are looking for 'distinguishable clusters of pixels' so that it would 1) distinguish itself from other pictures 2) liken itself to similar images.  I have used this beautifully crafted algorithm in several occasions in my research.  If you need more clarifications, let me know.

Comment: Dear Gary, the algorithm uses the extremes of differences of gaussians with different scales $k*\sigma$. From the illustration figure, it seems that one needs to take 5 different k values and then get 4 differences of Gaussians. If a point is the extrema of only 1 difference of Gaussians, should one select that point as a feature point? Thanks.

Comment: for POI(point-of-interests), you can impose your very own restrictions.  In one of my cases, there seemed to be some spatially dependent factors, so i imposed a spatial constraint when the points were matched against other points in other pictures.

Answer (score 0):

@Gary Tsui: can we use SIFT to search for similar parts in one image? If we copy some part of the image and paste it to another part of the same image, is there possibility to detect copy - pasted area by using SIFT ?